# Fourier transform of the dilation of a distribution

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Let $F$ a tempered distribution,  in my textbook the transform of $F$ is defined by $\hat{f}[ \phi]=F[\hat{\phi}]$ , having said that l'm interested in prove the following property of the Fourier transform:

$\mathbf{F}(F(tx))=|t|^{-n} \hat{f}(t^{-1} \xi)$

**My attempt:**

$(\mathbf{F}[F(tx)])[\phi]=F[\hat{(t\phi)}]=F[|t|^{-n} \hat{\phi }(t^{-1} \xi)]=|t|^{-n}F[\hat{\phi} (t^{-1} \xi)]=|t|^{-n} \hat{f}(t^{-1} \xi )$

This is correct? I am not sure that I have applied the definitions correctly. Best regards.

***Added: n is the number of dimensions***

Comment: What is $f$? Is $f=F$?

Comment: Okay. I've never seen anyone use $\hat f$ for the Fourier transform when the function is denoted $F$. More common is $\hat f$ when the function is $f$.

Comment: I know, is weird for me too but that’s the notation of the book (Introduction to Fourier Analysis and it’s applications from Gerald B.Folland)

Comment: Regarding your attempt: Can you explain why $\hat{t\phi} = |t|^{-n} \hat\phi(t^{-1}\xi)$?

Comment: Well that’s because if $ g: R^{n} \rightarrow{\mathbb{C}} $ is a function such that the Fourier transform exist then the same property I want to prove is valid, that is , $\hat{g}(tx)=|t|^{-n} \hat{g} ( t^{-1} x) $, so in particular this is true for test functions. Remark: by $g(tx)$ we understand $g(tx_{1},...,tx_{n}).

Comment: At the first equality I think that you take too many steps. Could split it up?

Comment: You mean an equality on each line?

Comment: No, I mean that I think that you do too much in the first equality, $(\mathbf{F}[F(tx)])[\phi]=F[\hat{(t\phi)}]$.

Comment: ah okay, you mean develop that first equality further?

Comment: Yes, expand it into smaller steps.

Comment: Now that I was trying to expand it I think I made a mistake, the dilation of a distribution $T$ is defined by $T(ax)[\phi]= \frac{1}{|a|^{n}} T[\phi(\frac{1}{a})]$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I got when I derived a formula to use as definition.

Comment: @md2perpe thanks! So using that definition we have that $\mathbf(F(tx))=\frac{1}{|t|^{n}} F[ \mathbf{ F}(\phi(x/t))]=\frac{1}{|t|^{n}}F[|t|^{n} \hat{\phi} (t \xi)]=F[\hat{\phi}(tx)]= |t|^{-n} \hat{f}(t^{-1} \xi )$ , right?

Comment: Isn't a $\mathbf F$ missing at the beginning? Except for that it looks correct.

Comment: hahaha yes , I forgot to put it , thank you very much! :D

Comment: You can use `\widehat` to get a caret that covers more than one symbol: $\widehat{xyz}.$

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks for that also @md2perpe ! Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How I would write it**

I here use the notation $\langle u, \varphi \rangle$ for the application of the distribution $u$ on the test function $\varphi.$

Introduce the operator $\lambda_t$ defined by $(\lambda_t f)(x) = f(tx).$ For a distribution $u$ we defined $\lambda_t u$ by $\langle \lambda_t u, \varphi \rangle = |t|^{-n} \langle u, \lambda_{1/t} \varphi \rangle.$

For a test function we have $\lambda_t\hat\varphi = |t|^{-n}\widehat{\lambda_{1/t}\varphi}.$ Using the above formulas, for a distribution we get
$$
\langle \widehat{\lambda_t u}, \varphi \rangle
= \langle \lambda_t u, \hat\varphi \rangle
= |t|^{-n} \langle u, \lambda_{1/t}\hat\varphi \rangle
= |t|^{-n} \langle u, |1/t|^{-n} \widehat{\lambda_t\varphi} \rangle \\
= \langle u, \widehat{\lambda_t\varphi} \rangle
= \langle \hat u, \lambda_t\varphi \rangle
= |t|^{-n} \langle \lambda_{1/t}\hat u, \varphi \rangle
,
$$
i.e. $\widehat{\lambda_t u} = |t|^{-n} \lambda_{1/t}\hat u.$

Comment: @MarkViola. The number of dimensions.

Comment: @MarkViola. It should have been in the question, where $n$ is first used.